# Reducing memory usage while making a trie/suffix tree in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree

I am trying to make a trie in c++, now what my basic data structure looks like is ..

```
struct node{
    int count; no of times this node has been visited.
    struct node* child[ALPHABET_SIZE]; // Let ALPHABET_SIZE be 26
}
```

When the string size gets large a lot of allocated memory is wasted. Like if we insert `"he"`
Our tree would be

```
root---->h--->e
    |--->e
```

We see that at root only `2/26th` of the memory allocated is being used. **How to improve ??**.

Answer (score 2):

Some very basic advice:

1. If your branching factor is predicted to be low, consider using something other than an array for the children. For example, you can have an array of letter to node* pairs and either do a linear or a binary search on them (if they are ordered). You can also use a map of some sort.
2. You can also play with smaller integer sizes for the count, if you don't expect counts in the millions/billions.
3. Instead of dynamically allocating nodes, you can get them from an arena based allocator (i.e., object pool), avoiding the heap allocation overhead that is often added to objects allocated on the heap.

Comment: Another trick I've seen with tries is to have two kinds of nodes.  A "prefix" which is what he has, and a "suffix", which is just "the rest of the string" and has no children.  h->e->l would have two suffix nodes, "p" and "lo".  You can save a fair amount of space this way, depending on how you work it

Comment: @MooingDuck Is that a special case of a Patricia trie, where nodes (regardless of position) with only one child are collapsed to eliminate link overhead?

Comment: @delnan: Never heard that name, but yeah, that's basically what it is

Comment: Another advantage of arena based allocators for something like this can be that the nodes are allocated close in memory, resulting in a better use of CPU caches.

Comment: I was searching the net for the same, this blog post pretty much solves my problem ..http://blog.ivank.net/trie-in-as3.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a fixed size array for each node, create an array with 1 element and resize it (replace it with a new array with size+1) when you insert a child. Inserting would be slower so you might test and change the resizing algorithm (size+1 or size*2 or size + size/2) so that there are fewer allocations if it gets too slow.

Answer (score 0):

Use [adjacency list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_lis).

Rather than a tree, we can create a list of nodes. A node will be dictionaries, each having "current value" (the alphabet) and "next state" (list of indices of the child nodes). We can add other required attributes in the node.

In your case:
The list will be -

> [{"value":"", "next_state":[1 ]}, {"value":"h", "next_state":[2]},
>   {"value":"e", "next_state":[ ]}]

Now say, we add "his". The list will be updated to :

> [{"value":"", "next_state": [1 ]}, {"value": "h", "next_state": [2 , 3]},
>   {"value":"e", "next_state":[ ]}, {"value":"i", "next_state":[4]}, {"value":"s", "next_state":[ ]},]

Notice, the `next_state` of node in index-1. We have two child nodes - "e" and "i".

It's very efficient and easy to implement. However, the trie operations will be considerably slower.